# Kotlin allCellInfo returns null when GPS is off

Tags: android, kotlin, location, cell

I am having an issue in app that has a function which shows current CellId.

Tested this app on various phones but some of them don't want to show even `allCellInfo` list, however, the app called Network Cell Info works perfect and shows everything about current CellId.

Only when I turn on GPS process works fine and I can see updates of CIDs.

Here is a piece of code (tested on SDK 29):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun getcids(manager: TelephonyManager): Pair<Int, String> {
    val cellInfoList = manager.allCellInfo
    if (cellInfoList != null) {
        for (networkType in cellInfoList) {
            if (networkType is CellInfoLte) {
                cid = networkType.cellIdentity.ci
                break
            }
            if (networkType is CellInfoWcdma) {
                val num = (networkType as CellInfoWcdma).cellIdentity
                cid = num.cid
                break
            }
            if (networkType is CellInfoGsm) {
                val num = (networkType as CellInfoGsm).cellIdentity
                cid = num.cid
                break
            }
        }
        return Pair(cid, cellInfoList.toString())
    }
    else{
        cid = 0
        return Pair(cid, "")
    }
}
```

What can be done here to get cell info on every phone?

**Update**

So far I tried this one. Downgraded SDK to 28 and got methods called `getNeighboringCellInfo()` and `getCellLocation()`. Tested `getCellLocation()` on some emulators with Android 8 and lower (as far as I know already Android 9 needs GPS to be turned on to get cell info). Everything was working fine without GPS until I decided to test it on my phones.

As a result app crash on `getCellLocation()` because it returns null value. However I also checked Network Cell Info where I saw that information about current connections shows without GPS.

Comment: The method docs indicate that it can return a CellInfoCdma as well, have you tried adding a check for this one?

Comment: I need to get any kind of cellinfo, which can be stored in list `allCellInfo`. The main problem is that GPS should be turned on in order to get not null but list with a content.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, Android 10 forced the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission to be granted. With that, the GPS needs to be on as well. Only then, if the information is available, this method will return the info you need. For Android 9.0 (API 28) or below, it should work as it expected.

So, here is what I would check.

1) To see if app holds permission `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

2) To see if app holds permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. (For API 29 and above)

3) To see if GPS is actually on. (For API 29 and above)

4) To check if there is a SIM attached to the device and there is service.

If these are in place and still the information is null, then I'd suspect the device itself on this case. I'm not sure what the issue could be if all of them are in place.

Comment: As far as I know Android 9 is the first who strictly needs GPS to be turned on. I have checked all the points you listed but unfortunately some devices on Android 8 and lower cannot obtain cellinfo without enabled GPS. I think this is also becuse of latest API version (28) that we have to use to build apps in Android Studio and upload them into Play Market.